# Ubuntu Server 14.04 TLS plus Hardware RAID

Tags: ubuntu, raid, storage, hardware-raid, ubuntu-14.04

I have just completed hadrware installation of my new RAID server which will run with Ubuntu Server OS. I have installed Ubuntu Server OS and everything run seemingly without problems.

However, I have few questions, I can not find answer to anywhere. I hope, I can find them here.

**Server Info:**

- Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 TLS
- [Adaptec RAID 72405](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-72405/)
- Ubuntu Server is installed on separate SATA HDD, which is not part of the Adaptec RAID field
- RAID Level 6 used

**Questions:**

1. Adaptec offers Ubuntu drivers for the RAID 72405 controller. Do I need to install them? Apparently, I can access the RAID folder. Is the Ubuntu driver needed only if the OS itself is installed on the RAID field?
2. I consider populating 50% of HDD bays now, and remaining 50% later, when needed. Will this be possible even if no Adaptec drivers are installed? After rebuilding the RAID 6, will I need to additionally increase Ubuntu partitions? Can the RAID 6 rebuild be done with all the data present, and the data won't be damaged after the rebuild?
3. How to correctly initialize the hardware RAID folder? Currently it it as /dev/sda on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm. -1? May I know why? I see absolutely nothing wrong on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The drivers are part of the kernel, they do not require separate installation. If there were no drivers, the disks would not even be visible on the system.
2. Yes partition sizes will need to grow if the underlying storage grows. You should use LVM if you plan to do this, otherwise the system will need to be taken offline to grow the partition.
3. `/dev/sdxx` is how the array should be displayed. The disks themselves are `/dev/sgxx`.

Comment: Hi Jordanm, thanks for great responses. It looks that you are experienced in this subject. Woudl you please advise to purchase all 100% of HDDs right now and install them, or is it completely correct to purchase 50% now and 50% later? Don't I have to be affraid of data loss during the rebuild process later? As my RAID is going to have 88 TB, to archive 44 TB will probaby be really challenging during RAID 6 rebuild, so I would like to avoid backing up all this data.